# MonoDevelop ValaBinding install failed

Tags: monodevelop, vala, ubuntu-13.04

I installed monodevelop in ubuntu 13.04 from git with the help of README.md, but I received an error

```
checking for LIBVALA... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libvala-0.12 >= 0.12) were not met:

No package 'libvala-0.12' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBVALA_CFLAGS
and LIBVALA_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have installed libvala-0.20-0 and libvala-0.20-dev by apt-get.
I have googled for this question and found some links,but helpless.
my mono was at version 3.6.1.

THX FOR HELP.

---

update 2014-06-19
I found the config.log file and see the error

```
configure:4075: checking for LIBVALA
configure:4084: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libvala-0.12 >= $LIBVALA_REQUIRED_VERSION"
Package libvala-0.12 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvala-0.12.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

Although I have installed libvala-0.20-0 and libvala-0.20-dev, I doesn't own a libvala-0.**.pc file.

What can I do the next?

---

I have resolved thest problem by finding a libvala-0.12.pc file :)

Comment: are you interested in using vala?

Comment: Hi @knocte ,in fact I know few about vala, I'm less interested in gnome -_- . I just want to run .net in ubuntu, so I have a try. Now I'm a little interested in how would that be (can not installed).

Comment: But if you know how to reconfigure monodevelop and remove vala extras, please teach me. I should build the monodevelop at first. The answel can be looking for after.@knocte

Comment: My libvala-0.20-0 is installed in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.`/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libvala-0.20-0
/usr/share/doc/libvala-0.20-0/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libvala-0.20-0/THANKS
/usr/share/doc/libvala-0.20-0/README
/usr/share/doc/libvala-0.20-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libvala-0.20-0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libvala-0.20-0/NEWS.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvala-0.20.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvala-0.20.so.0
` this is the result of `dpkg -L libvala-0.20-0` if there's any impact?

Answer (score 1):

While the Vala language, valac, and most of the bindings distributed with Vala are meant to be API stable, libvala is not.  libvala-0.20 provides a very different API/ABI from libvala-0.12, and apparently MonoDevelop's Vala plugin hasn't been updated since Vala 0.12.

If you don't want the Vala plugin, I'm sure MonoDevelop provides a way to disable it (probably passing `--disable-vala` or something similar to `./configure`).  If you need the Vala plugin, though, you'll have to install libvala-0.12 or update the plugin to use a newer version of libvala.

Comment: THX for your information, I removed libvala-0.20 and find a package contains libvala-0.12.pc. Now the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

now the problem is solved.
I used cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu for my apt-get.
These's no libvala-**.pc file in the package.
So whatever version I installed by apt-get, I can not get a libvala-*.pc file.
I searched in google for libvala-12.0.pc and changed my source to cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, then I got that file.
Now I can run my monodevelop with valabinding.

Thx for @nemequ , I didn't use a higher libvala, so I don't know if it will be different when using a libvala-hight-than-12.0.pc file.

Hope these is usefull for others.

If you don't want to install vavabind after configure once ,just use `./configure --select`, it's written in README. My bad :(

Comment: what does the valabinding do?